# How to call fullpagejs methods from child components in vue-fullpage wrapper?

Tags: vue.js, fullpage.js

I don't understand how you are supposed to call `fullpagejs` methods from vue child components, or rather any component that isn't the top-level `App.vue` component.

The vue wrapper for fullpage restricts you to using the fullpage component only once in the whole app, so I can't call any methods using `this.$refs.fullpage.api` in any subcomponents.

I want to have some clickable elements that trigger navigation methods like `moveTo` nested within lower-level components.

How did the author intend vue apps to use methods outside of App.vue?

The only thing I've been able to find that works seems rather hacky; I have the child component calling a method from App.vue via `$root.children[0]`.

Should I instead be passing the fullpage ref as a prop somehow?

I know about props and events but it seems incredibly tedious to have to write code to bubble events up 4-5 layers of subcomponents.

I tried making an event bus using a separate vue instance, but the event bus instance did not have any access to the methods in App.vue.

It feels like I'm missing something.

Does fullpage just require you to consolidate all the method calls to the fullpage api within `App.vue`?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
//where --> var vm = new Vue({...}) if calling it from outside.
vm.$refs.fullpage.build();

//or, when calling it from inside the Vue component methods:
this.$refs.fullpage.build();
```

You can also use the global object living in the window object: `fullpage_api`. So for example: `fullpage_api.moveSectionDown()`.

If you are aware of how to improve for your use case, please feel free to create a pull request I'll happily merge it into the component! :)